# View all discounts applied to a cart and remove discounts from cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, discounts

On my cart page I have the coupon code form to apply discounts to the order. Underneath the form I want to list all the coupons applied to the cart with an button to remove each discount.

As in the example template I can access the latest coupon applied to the cart, but am no sure how to list all that have been applied to the cart and how to remove a coupon if a customer wanted to.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You've sort of answered your own question - Commerce only allows one coupon on a cart at any time (currently).

To determine if a coupon is set, and print the code, it's basically:

```twig
{% if cart.couponCode %}
     {{ cart.couponCode }}
{% endif %}
```

You CAN have discounts applied as well as coupons, though.
With those, you can look through with something like this (removing the coupons if you've previously printed that)

```twig
{% for adjustment in cart.adjustments if adjustment.type == "Discount" %}
    {% set isCoupon = adjustment.optionsJson.code ? true : false %} 
        {{ adjustment.description }}
        ...etc
```